# Separating validation logic from business logic in asp.net MVC 5 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an asp.net MVC 5 website.

I am using data annotations on the model for validation - eg

```
[Required]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

However, if I want to do something a bit more complicated with validation, say require a date to be in the future - all examples I have seen just perform validation in the controller - eg:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel vm)
{
    // check date is in future
    if (vm.mydate < DateTime.Now())
        ModelState.IsValid = false;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Business Logic
    }
```

Even Web Forms let you separate validation logic out into a CustomValidator. It feels wrong putting validation logic into a controller directly and mixing it with business logic.

(note - while I would like an answer to how to do this specific problems with Data Annotations - I would also like an answer to the bigger question about separating validation logic out).

Is there a best practice, or a Framework mandated, way to separate this out? I haven't seen it in any example sites found online.

Am I unduly worrying about this - is this part of the purpose of a controller to perform validation? Should my business logic instead be in the Model? (the BL is largely really just writing to a database so maybe that doesn't even count as BL?).

thx.

Comment: you can try  RangeAttribute   (MSDN)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx

Comment: OK - thanks - but how about my bigger point about separating out validation logic?

Comment: You could either make a custom model binder that does the validation while binding the model or you would create a custom action filter to validate the model

Comment: i found this example ( http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/)  , sorry i haven;t tried this

Comment: Try out Fluent Validations - https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc

Comment: inherit from IValidatableObject.  You can then implement whatever you want in the validate method  http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/custom-validation-with.html

Comment: Consider a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` or similar validation attribute to give you both client of server side validation (or you can write your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke looks interesting - though hasn't been updated since 2012 and only 8000 downloads, seems a bit risky to take this on as a dependency - nice idea though.

Comment: @Emil will RangeAttribute work to specify date must be in the future only?

Comment: @niico, Just because it has not been updated for a while does not mean it does not work :) - but its easy enough to write your own attribute  (and note that a `RangeAttribute` wont work)

Comment: @niico have you looked at the link i provided? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your custom Validation Attribute.

Create a new class and add:

```
public sealed class ValidFutureDate : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            DateTime InputDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value);

            if (InputDate <= DateTime.Now)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Inputed date must be in the future.");
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

You need to add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

And in your ViewModel, you can use the attribute like all the rest:

```
[Required]
[ValidFutureDate]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: This lets me put the annotation on - but it doesn't raise an error of the date is in the past.

Comment: did you included in your view jqueryval?

Comment: <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

Comment: should this not work on the server even if it doesn't work in the views in any case?

Comment: For me it works just fine: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "form-control" })` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`. This is in my view

Comment: I worked it out - I wasn't checking model state in the post action method - thanks!