# How to apply an filter to a controller ? using DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using `Autofac`

I have a webapi controller **MyWebApiController** to which I need to apply a filter **MyNewActionFilter**. In `Autofac`, I can simply do as below:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyNewActionFilter>()
                .AsWebApiExceptionFilterFor<MyWebApiController>()
                .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(MyWebApiController));
```

this is similar to below:

```
[MyNewActionFilter]
public class MyWebApiController : ApiController
```

How to do the same for a MVC controller?

My MVC Controller: **HomeController** and my MVC filter is **TrackPackageFilter**

I tried,

```
builder.RegisterType<HomeController>()
            .AsActionFilterFor<TrackPackageFilter>
            .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

But this format isn't correct., meaning `there was no extension method or method called AsActionFilterFor`.

Can anyone shed some insight ?

Comment: Take a look at this response [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135387/separating-validation-logic-from-business-logic-in-asp-net-mvc-5-controller/40162422#40162422)

Comment: I am asking in the scope of **autofac** injection. Above link talks a different thing.

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate on "format isn't correct", share your research.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an overlooked error.

Did not include an `using` directive : **using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;**

My Resharper/VS did not automatically find it for me :(

Anyways, worked out now :)